# Combined mean and standard deviation from a collection of NumPy arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have Numpy arrays with shapes

```
(682, 89, 138)
(2668, 76, 89)
(491, 62, 48)
```

How should I calculate the mean and standard deviation of all three arrays combined? If they were the same shapes, I could use `np.stack()` and then get the mean and std of the resulting array.

Is it possible to do this with different sized dimensions? Or would I have to reshape before getting the mean and std?

Comment: flatten, append, compute

Comment: How would you define these calculations for these arrays, combined?  Not only is the shape different, but so is the total number of elements.

Comment: I want to get one value for mean and one value for std. The arrays would be stacked on top of the other if the shapes matched.

Comment: @PaulH Appending/stacking/concatenating would be costly for such big NumPy arrays to create an even bigger array. OP probably wants to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the formula of `standard deviation` and `mean` to compute those two scalar values for all input arrays without concatenating/stacking (that could be costly specially on large NumPy arrays). Let's do it in steps - mean and then standard deviation, as it seems we could use `mean` in `std` computations.

**Getting the combined mean value :**

So, we will start with the mean/averaging. For this, we would get the summation scalar for each array. Then, get the total summation and finally divide by the number of elements in all arrays.

**Getting the combined standard deviation value :**

For standard deviation, we have the formula as :

[image]

So, we will use the combined mean value obtained from previous step, use the `std` formula to get the squared differentiation, divide by the total number of elements across all arrays and then apply square root.

**Implementation**

Let's say the input arrays are `a` and `b`, we would have one solution, like so -

```
N = float(a.size + b.size)
mean_ = (a.sum() + b.sum())/N
std_ = np.sqrt((((a - mean_)**2).sum() + ((b - mean_)**2).sum())/N)
```

**Sample run for verification**

```
In [266]: a = np.random.rand(3,4,2)
     ...: b = np.random.rand(2,5,3)
     ...: 

In [267]: N = float(a.size + b.size)
     ...: mean_ = (a.sum() + b.sum())/N
     ...: std_ = np.sqrt((((a - mean_)**2).sum() + ((b - mean_)**2).sum())/N)
     ...: 

In [268]: mean_
Out[268]: 0.47854757879348042

In [270]: std_
Out[270]: 0.27890341338373376
```

Now, to verify, let's stack and then use relevant ufuncs -

```
In [271]: A = np.hstack((a.ravel(), b.ravel()))

In [273]: A.mean()
Out[273]: 0.47854757879348037

In [274]: A.std()
Out[274]: 0.27890341338373376
```

---

**List of arrays as input**

For a list holding all those arrays, we need to iterate through them, like so -

```
A = [a,b,c] # input list of arrays

N = float(sum([i.size for i in A]))
mean_ = sum([i.sum() for i in A])/N
std_ = np.sqrt(sum([((i-mean_)**2).sum() for i in A])/N)
```

Sample run -

```
In [301]: a = np.random.rand(3,4,2)
     ...: b = np.random.rand(2,5,3)
     ...: c = np.random.rand(7,4)
     ...: 

In [302]: A = [a,b,c] # input list of arrays
     ...: N = float(sum([i.size for i in A]))
     ...: mean_ = sum([i.sum() for i in A])/N
     ...: std_ = np.sqrt(sum([((i-mean_)**2).sum() for i in A])/N)
     ...: print mean_, std_
     ...: 
0.47703535428 0.293308550786

In [303]: A = np.hstack((a.ravel(), b.ravel(), c.ravel()))
     ...: print A.mean(), A.std()
     ...: 
0.47703535428 0.293308550786
```

Comment: The issue is that I have many arrays (over 1,000) that I want to get the combined mean and std. Normally, I use ` combined = np.stack([arr for i in arrays])` and then call combined.mean() and combined.std(), however this assumes all arrays can be stacked.