# Efficiently Standardizing Images in a Numpy Array

Tags: python, image, numpy, computer-vision, normalization

I have a numpy array of images of shape `(N, H, W, C)` where `N` is the number of images, `H` the image height, `W` the image width and `C` the RGB channels.

I would like to standardize my images channel-wise, so for each image I would like to channel-wise subtract the image channel's mean and divide by its standard deviation.

I did this in a loop, which worked, however it is very inefficient and as it makes a copy my RAM is getting too full.

```
def standardize(img):
    mean = np.mean(img)
    std = np.std(img)
    img = (img - mean) / std
    return img

for img in rgb_images:
    r_channel = standardize(img[:,:,0])
    g_channel = standardize(img[:,:,1])
    b_channel = standardize(img[:,:,2])
    normalized_image = np.stack([r_channel, g_channel, b_channel], axis=-1)
    standardized_images.append(normalized_image)
standardized_images = np.array(standardized_images)
```

How can I do this more efficiently making use of numpy's capabilities?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perform the ufunc reductions (mean, std) along the second and third axes, while keeping the dims intact that help in  [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) later on with the division step -

```
mean = np.mean(rgb_images, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
std = np.std(rgb_images, axis=(1,2), keepdims=True)
standardized_images_out = (rgb_images - mean) / std
```

Boost the performance further by re-using the average values to compute standard-deviation, according to its formula and hence inspired by [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398247/) , like so -

```
std = np.sqrt(((rgb_images - mean)**2).mean((1,2), keepdims=True))
```

Packaging into a function with the axes for reductions as a parameter, we would have -

```
from __future__ import division

def normalize_meanstd(a, axis=None): 
    # axis param denotes axes along which mean & std reductions are to be performed
    mean = np.mean(a, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    std = np.sqrt(((a - mean)**2).mean(axis=axis, keepdims=True))
    return (a - mean) / std

standardized_images = normalize_meanstd(rgb_images, axis=(1,2))
```

Comment: Can you explain how the axis argument works in this case? I couldn't see that this is possible. And its necessary to keepdims to do the subtraction and division later on? Besides, great answer! I verify tomorrow and give you the credits.

Comment: @Chris This should help out on axis - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html#methods. `keepdims` is necessary is to keep the no. of dims, as needed for broadcasting later on.

Comment: Just to make something clear, your operations make a copy as well, right? Is there a way to make the subtraction and division operations in-place?

Comment: @Chris At the last step, use `out = ` param for `numpy.subtract` and `numpy.divide` to replace those corresponding operations.

Comment: so `np.subtract(rgb_images, mean, out=rgb_images)` works? Or would it cause problems to write into the same array as the one used as the first argument? And what is the difference compared to `rgb_images -= mean`?